# How to build datatables in react components?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, django, reactjs

I am using `react`, and while checking for `datatables(jquery plugin)` to work with `react`, I found gigatables-react.

In documentation, it seems nice and screenshots are very cool. but while implementing gigatables,

I followed the steps,

```
-> npm i gigatables-react
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SideBar from './../account_upload/sidebar';
import { Reactables, Header } from 'gigatables-react';

var settings = {
      struct: {// all in
            search: ['top'],
            rowsSelector: ['asc', 'top', 'bottom'],
            pagination: ['bottom']
      },
      requestType: 'POST',
      ajax: '/domain_ip/',
      columns: [
            {data: "id"},
            {data: "desc"},
            {data: "title"},
            {data: "date"},
            {data: "types"},
            {data: "info"}
      ]
};

class Accounts extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{"display": "inline-flex"}}>
                <div className="custom_sidebar">
                    <SideBar />
                </div>
                <div className="content">
                    <Reactables settings={settings}>
                        <Header data="id">ID</Header>
                        <Header data="desc">Description</Header>
                        <Header data="title">Name</Header>
                        <Header data="date">Date</Header>
                        <Header data="types">Date</Header>
                        <Header data="info">Info</Header>
                    </Reactables>,
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Accounts;
```

What is wrong in this?? I  am getting error in console as,

```
accountsSet-ccb24f5e97f47f7e0ca9.js:sourcemap:29807
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'csv' of undefined
at t.value (accountsSet-ccb24f5e97f47f7e0ca9.js:sourcemap:29807)
at t.value (accountsSet-ccb24f5e97f47f7e0ca9.js:sourcemap:29807)
```

How do I resolve this??

Comment: Maybe your ajax setting to get your data isn't quite right and it is defaulting to csv as the data source. (I have no clue, just suggesting a thought)

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue...

Comment: Actually i tried datatables.net [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables.net), and i got it working [Results](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/47474/need-help-for-using-editor-datatable-as-react-components#latest)

Comment: here is a datatables.net usage [example](https://medium.com/@zbzzn/integrating-react-and-datatables-not-as-hard-as-advertised-f3364f395dfa)

Answer (score -1):

STEP1: Install jQuery and Datatables node modules `npm i --save datatables.net jquery`.

STEP2: import both jQuery and Datatables

```
const $ = require('jquery');
$.DataTable = require('datatables.net');
```

STEP3: define component

```
class Table extends Component { 
    componentDidMount() {
        $(this.refs.main).DataTable({
           dom: '<"data-table-wrapper"t>',
           data: this.props.names,
           columns,
           ordering: false
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
       $('.data-table-wrapper')
       .find('table')
       .DataTable()
       .destroy(true);
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table ref="main" />
            </div>);
    }
}

const columns = [
    {
        title: 'Name',
        width: 120,
        data: 'name'
    },
    {
        title: 'Nickname',
        width: 180,
        data: 'nickname'
    },
];
```

Source [integrating-react-and-datatables](https://medium.com/@zbzzn/integrating-react-and-datatables-not-as-hard-as-advertised-f3364f395dfa)